# StructureMap interceptor and DynamicProxy

Tags: .net, aop, structuremap, dynamic-proxy

I am trying to upgrade StructureMap from 2.6 to 4.7. I had an interceptor which creates and return proxy.

```
    public object Process(object target, IContext context)
    {
        Type targetType = target.GetType();

        var instanceRef = _container.Model.AllInstances.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ReturnedType == targetType);

        if (instanceRef != null)
        {
            Type interfaceToProxy = instanceRef.PluginType;
            return _proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTargetInterface(interfaceToProxy, target, new[] { (IInterceptor) new AspectInterceptor(_aspectConfiguration) });
        }

        return target;
    }

    public bool MatchesType(Type type)
    {
        object[] customAttributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (EnableAspects), true);

        return customAttributes.Length > 0;
    }
```

How can I refactor this to get it working on StructureMap 4.7